Computing $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a}}{x^2 + x + 1}dx$ for $a\in (-1,1), a\neq 0$
I am trying to compute $$I = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a}}{x^2 + x + 1}dx$$ for $a\in (-1,1), a\neq 0$. I considered the contour integral $$\int_C \frac{z^{a}}{z^2 + z + 1}dz$$ where $C$ is the keyhole contour with branch cut along the real axis. Choose $\arg(z) \in (0,2\pi)$ and consider $a\in (0,1)$ for now to ignore any argument problems which may arise if $a$ were negative. Then the poles of the function occur at $e^{2\pi i/3}, e^{4\pi i /3}$ and so by the Residue Theorem I found $$\int_C \frac{z^{a}}{z^2 + z + 1}dz = \frac{2\pi i}{\sqrt{3}}(e^{2\pi i a/3} - e^{4\pi i a/3})$$ The integrals along $C_R, C_{\varepsilon}$ vanish as $R\to\infty, \varepsilon \to 0$. If we call $L_1$ the portion of the line segment above the real axis, I found $$\int_{L_1} \frac{z^{a}}{z^2 + z + 1}dz = I$$ Similarly, if $L_2$ is the portion of the line segment below the real axis, I found $$\int_{L_2} \frac{z^{a}}{z^2 + z + 1}dz = -e^{2\pi i a}I$$ Combining the information together, it gives $$I = \frac{2\pi i}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\frac{e^{2\pi i a/3} - e^{4\pi ia/3}}{1+ e^{2\pi ia}}\right)$$ But I should have RHS being something in $\mathbb{R}$. I cannot see where I've gone wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

RHS seems to be in $\mathbb{R}$. Divide the numerator and denominator by $e^{\pi ia}$ and change it in the form of sine and cosines.

On doing so I found that $I = \frac{2\pi \sin(\pi a/3)}{\sqrt{3}\cos(\pi a)}$ but this is incorrect. E.g. for $a=1/2$, $I$ has a finite value but the RHS expression does not.

I think the denominator should be $1-e^{2\pi ia}$

Do you get one $i$ from the difference between the poles and another $i$ from the $2\pi i$

You should have found the following residues.
$$\underset{z=e^{i2\pi/3}}{\operatorname{Res}} f(z) = \lim_{z\to e^{i2\pi/3}} \frac{|z|^a e^{i a \arg z}}{z-e^{i4\pi/3}} = \frac{e^{ia2\pi/3}}{e^{i2\pi/3}-e^{i4\pi/3}} = -\frac{i e^{i 2 a \pi/3}}{\sqrt3}$$
$$\underset{z=e^{i4\pi/3}}{\operatorname{Res}} f(z) = \lim_{z\to e^{i2\pi/3}} \frac{|z|^a e^{i a \arg z}}{z-e^{i2\pi/3}} = \frac{e^{i a 4\pi/3}}{e^{i4\pi/3}-e^{i2\pi/3}} = \frac{i e^{i 4a\pi/3}}{\sqrt3}$$
Their sum is
$$\sum \operatorname{Res} f(z) = \frac i{\sqrt3} \left(e^{i4a\pi/3} - e^{i2a\pi/3}\right)$$
whereas yours appears to be missing a factor of $i$. By the residue theorem,
$$\oint_C f(z) \, dz = \left(1-e^{ia2\pi}\right) I = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt3} \left(e^{i2a\pi/3} - e^{i4a\pi/3}\right)$$
$$\implies I = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt3} \frac{e^{i2a\pi/3}-e^{i4a\pi/3}}{1-e^{ia2\pi}} 
= \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt3} \frac{e^{-ia\pi/3}-e^{ia\pi/3}}{e^{-ia\pi}-e^{ia\pi}} = \boxed{\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt3} \frac{\sin\frac{a\pi}3}{\sin(a\pi)}}$$
We can confirm that for $a=\dfrac12$, this result matches the integral value.
